# What's the grammar meaning of 'typename List::node_type& elem_node = elem->*list.node;'?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct

I read code of `mysql` source code in *line 148*, [source code link here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/storage/innobase/include/ut0lst.h)

I got confused here:

```
typename List::node_type&   elem_node = elem->*list.node;
```

It's so strange: `->*`.
What's the grammar meaning?

Comment: Have you tried searching for it yourself? Something like googling "C++ operators" and reading through a few top results? What has that told you, and what do you not understand from that?

Comment: @Angew, it is really not easy for me to search operator '->*'.

Comment: "pointer to member" is the name of this operator: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_pointer-to-member_access_operators

Comment: @Rubby How about searching for "C++ operators" and then finding this one manually in the results? Such as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators) or [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->*` notation is needed because `list` is a pointer to a member. Here's a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    // 'ptr' now points to the 'b' member of some 'S' value.
    int (S::*ptr) = &S::b;

    S *x = new S;
    x->*ptr = 5;

    std::cout << x->b << '\n';
}
```

This program prints '5'. The `ptr` pointer is made to be of type `int (S::*)`, i.e. a pointer to some `int` member of a `S` struct. It's initialized to point to the `b` member.

Of course, to actually *do* something sensible with it you need to specify *which* `S` struct to modify. That's done via

```
x->*ptr
```

Which can be read as "the member of the `x` value which is dereferenced by the `ptr` pointer".